# send data to html dashboard in python flask while having dictionary in a function parameter

Tags: python, function, flask

I want to send data to html in flask framework, i have a function which receives dictionary as a parameter, then there are several functions applied on dictionary. after that final result i want to render in to html page. Its been 48 hours i am trying from different blogs but didn't get precise solution.

```
imports ...
from other file import other_functions
from other file import other_functions_2
from other file import other_functions_3

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='templates/')

@app.route("/dashboard")
def calculate_full_eva_web(input:dict):

   calculate_gap = other_functions(input)
   calculate_matrix = other_functions_2(input)
   average = other_functions_3(input)
   data = dict{'calculate_gap':calculate_gap, 'calculate_matrix':calculate_matrix,'average':average}

   return render_template('pages/dashboard.html', data = data) 

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**TRACEBACK**
[image: Always get this error]

Comment: This doesn't really make sense. Where are you expecting that dict to come from?

Comment: @DanielRoseman dict is comming from function in other file of project, in def calculate_full_eva_web(input) there are several functions which applied on dict and in result it gives calculated output, i want to render these outputs on html dashboard, .. or any other way you want me to work ?

Comment: Now this makes even less sense. How is it supposed to be getting from that other function into this one?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i am receiving payload in other file after receive payload it validates input body of payload, and checking authentication token of payload after that payload dictionary is passed to this file for calculation and operations and after calculation i have to render these calculated data in to html dashboard. does this make sense to you ?

Comment: No, not really. Perhaps you should show this "other file".

Comment: Instead of `data = dict{...}`, do: `data = dict()` and `data['calculate_gap']= calculate_gap`, etc....

Comment: @codrelphi still same error calculate full eva web requried 1 positional arugment input

Answer (score 0):

Methods that Flask can route to don't take dictionaries as inputs, and the arguments they do take need to be matches by a pattern in the route. (See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#url-route-registrations)

You'd get the same error if you changed

```
@app.route("/dashboard")
def calculate_full_eva_web(input:dict):
```

to

```
@app.route("/dashboard")
def calculate_full_eva_web(input):
```

Your path forward depends on how you want to pass data when you make the request. You can pass key/value pairs via URL parameters and retrieve them via the `request.args` object. That might be close enough to what you want. (You'll need to remove the argument declaration from `calculate_full_eva_web()`)

Something like

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/dashboard')
def calculate_full_eva_web():
    input = request.args
    ...
```

Comment: Please can you provide a small example of code what you said ?

Comment: Added an untested fragment above

Comment: thank you for adding the code snippet .. but there is function in parent file, which calls "calculate_full_eva_web(input)"

and then in this file def calculate_full_eva_web() is supposed to recieve input  as a parameter? if i put input = request.args 
it throws error.

Comment: `calculate_full_eva_web()` is both called directly and wrapped in a `route()`? Your code is tripping over itself. I think it's best if you find someone nearby to help you directly.